# PHP Insert not Working Properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following lines of PHP code in my file along with some other code:

```
$command = "INSERT INTO inventory_items (Index, Name, Price) VALUES (NULL, 'Diamond', '3.99')";
$insertion = mysql_query($command) or die(mysql_error());
if ($insertion == FALSE)
{
 echo "Error: Insert failed.";
}
else
{
 echo "Insert successful.";
}
```

It keeps returning this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Index, Name, Price) VALUES (NULL, 'Diamond', '3.99')' at line 1
```

myAdmin says I am using MySQL client version 5.0.91. What am I doing wrong? I just can't figure it out! I tried searching a lot...

Comment: Did any of the answers here solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Index is a reserved word in MySQL and as such, you need to either change the name of the column, or escape it with backticks. Try this `$command`:

```
$command = "INSERT INTO inventory_items (`Index`, Name, Price) VALUES (NULL, 'Diamond', '3.99')";
```

Read more about reserved words here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: I don't see "db" on that list, but I ran into the same problem as the OP. I eventually changed my table name to "dbentry" and it worked. So, is there an additional reserved list I don't know about or was I doing something else wrong?

Comment: @Bryan: If all you changed was your table name, then I guess db is another reserved word. Not sure if there's another list other than that one though.

Comment: As a general rule you should always enclose column names and table names with backticks. If a future version of (my)SQL introduces a new reserved word your once working query may fail.

Comment: @DeveloperChris: I agree. That actually happened to me a few years ago. I can't recall the column name, but I believe it was actually `date` or `id`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$command = "INSERT INTO inventory_items (`Index`, Name, Price) VALUES (NULL, 'Diamond', '3.99');";
```

[MySQL reserved words and how to treat them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: I have tried as you have said but have gotten the same error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Index, Name, Price) VALUES (NULL, 'Diamond', '3.99')' at line 1

Comment: It's not @ but ``Index`` instead.

Comment: yeeeeeeeeah thanks brother :D:D:D so...whats up with the weird quotations?

Comment: @user: It's how MySQL handles quoting identifiers, not entirely sure why they picked those, but that's the way the cookie crumbles :P

Comment: It must be backticks = ( ` ).

Comment: Yes, index is a reserved word. See the link above for a complete list of MySQL reserved words. Every reserved word must be surrounded by backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the columns in your inventory_items table are:

```
Index
Name
Price
```

And that you have the Index field set to AUTO_INCREMENT.

The best thing is probably to remove that field from your insert statement.

Try

```
$command = "INSERT INTO inventory_items (Name, Price) VALUES ('Diamond', '3.99')";
```

Since you're not inserting an Index anyway.

Hope that helps!